# Javascript Alert before redirecting in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using following code to display message while updating in update panel

```
string jv = "alert('Time OutAlert');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "msg", jv, true);
```

It works fine.

But when I use Redirect after it it loads the page without displaying the message. I want user to see the message and after clicking on "ok" it should redirect.

```
string jv = "alert('Time OutAlert');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "msg", jv, true);
Response.Redirect("~/Nextpage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Display the alert with javascript and then do the redirect with the same:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"redirect",
"alert('Time OutAlert'); window.location='" + 
Request.ApplicationPath + "Nextpage.aspx';",true);
```

Comment: This solution also works when using routing names instead of full page names.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that, the way you try because the message is running on the client side, but you make the redirect on code behind before the page loading to show the message.

The way to do that is to call right after the message a client side redirect as:

```
window.location = "NextPage.asps";
```

Comment: How could I add this to the builtin function?

Answer (score 0):

## This Works fine

```
                string message = "Upadate Successfull !!";
                string url = "/Post.aspx";
                string script = "{ alert('";
                script += message;
                script += "');";
                script += "window.location = '";
                script += url;
                script += "'; }";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
```