# How to show Javascript Alert message before redirecting to same page in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried with below code to redirect to same page after showing alert message during button click.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType(), "AlertMsg", "alert('Success');", True)
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
```

But page redirect to same page without throwing Javascript alert message. How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

Before asking a question .. please have look on already asked question on same topics .... Here are different answer link on `stackoverflow`..

[How to get alert message before redirect a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570766/how-to-get-alert-message-before-redirect-a-page)

[Javascript Alert before redirecting in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209822/javascript-alert-before-redirecting-in-asp-net)

[Asp.net Webform Display Alert and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782354/asp-net-webform-display-alert-and-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"page redirect",
"alert('Message'); window.location='" + 
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri+"';",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "AlertMsg", "alert('Success');window.location ='"+Request.Url.AbsoluteUri+"';", True)
```