# jQuery code not working when button click in asp.net content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

this is my Master Page Page Directive

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashMaster.master.cs" Inherits="TNC.DashMaster" %>
```

this is my content Page Directive

```
<%@ Page Title="Dashboard Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/DashMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="TNC.dash.Dashboard" %>
```

in my content page i have 3 tabs **{ Profile Tab, Picture Tab, Change Password Tab }**
when i update my profile information its updating to database file but after updating i want to show Message `Profile info updated Successfully..` through code behind by using

```
protected void btnDashProfileSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = _editUserPresenter.UpdateProfile(Convert.ToInt64(txtdashuserID.Text),
                                         txtdashusername.Text,
                                         txtdashfirstname.Text.Trim(),
                                         txtdashlastname.Text.Trim(),
                                         ddlGender.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                                         txtdashEmailID.Text,
                                         txtdashContactNo.Text.Trim(),
                                         txtdashdesignation.Text.Trim(),
                                         txtdashqualification.Text.Trim());
        if (i > 0)
        {
            //calling Display you can find this method below
            Display(Convert.ToInt64(txtdashuserID.Text));
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "editProfile", "$('.alert-success').show(); $('.alert-success').html('Profile Update Successfully...'); ", true);
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx?userID=10000000022&username=srikanth442#divprofile");
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "editProfileFail", "$('.alert-danger').show(); $('.alert-danger').html('Profile Update Fail. Please Try Again');", true);
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx?userID=10000000022&username=srikanth442#divprofile");
        }
    }
```

i'm call this Display method serveral places

```
public void Display(Int64 UserID)
        {
            DataSet ds = _userServices.GetUserByUserID(UserID);
            string Username = Extension.Decrypt(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString());
            Session["username"] = Username;
            _userSession.LoggedIn = true;
            _userSession.Username = Username;

            foreach (DataRow dw in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                txtdashuserID.Text = dw["userid"].ToString();
                txtdashusername.Text = Username;
                txtdashfirstname.Text = dw["firstname"].ToString();
                txtdashlastname.Text = dw["lastname"].ToString();
                txtdashEmailID.Text = dw["emailid"].ToString();
                txtdashContactNo.Text = dw["phone"].ToString();
                txtdashdesignation.Text = dw["designation"].ToString();
                txtdashqualification.Text = dw["qualification"].ToString();
                if (dw["accountype"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lbldashAccountType.Text = "Free";
                }
                if (dw["usertype"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lbldashUserType.Text = "General";
                }
                if (dw["roles"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lbldashRole.Text = "User";
                }
                Label lblUsername = (Label)Master.FindControl("lbldashfullname");
                Label lblAccountCreatedDate = (Label)Master.FindControl("lbldashAccountCreatedon");
                Label lblAccountUpdatedDate = (Label)Master.FindControl("lbldashprofileupdate");
                Session["username"] = Username;
                Session["AccCreateDate"] = String.Format("{0:dddd, dd MMM yyyy}", dw["account_create_date"]);
                Session["AccUpdatedDate"] = String.Format("{0:dddd, dd MMM yyyy}", dw["update_account_date"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Alert before redirecting in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209822/javascript-alert-before-redirecting-in-asp-net)

Comment: @VishalSuthar : its worked yesterday but its not working today ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key",
             "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + "$('.btnDashProfileSubmit').live(\"click\", function () {$('.alert-success').show(); $('.alert-success').html('Profile Update Successfully...');});" + "</script>"
             );
```