# Show alert message before redirecting to other page ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have found a lot of examples but I don't know why these are not working for me. I have tried these but in vain.

- [How to show Javascript Alert message before redirecting to same page
  in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560508/how-to-show-javascript-alert-message-before-redirecting-to-same-page-in-vb-net)
- [Javascript Alert before redirecting in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209822/javascript-alert-before-redirecting-in-asp-net)
- [Asp.net Webform Display Alert and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782354/asp-net-webform-display-alert-and-redirect)

I have also tried the following:

```
String message = "Session Expired! Log In Again.";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
    string.Format("alert('{0}');window.location.href = 'default.aspx'", 
    message.Replace("'", @"\'").Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r")), 
    true);
```

and

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "redirect", 
    "alert('Session Expired! Log In Again.'); 
    window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Account/login.aspx';", 
    true);
```

and

```
Response.Write("
<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Session Expired');
    window.location='~/Account/Login.aspx';
</script>");
```

but all of these are not redirecting to the login page just showing the alert message.

Comment: Can anybody tells me that why is this line displaying alert message but not redirecting to the login page.
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "redirect", 
    "alert('Session Expired! Log In Again.'); 
     window.location='~" + Request.ApplicationPath + 
    "Account/login.aspx';", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
window.location.href="Account/Login.aspx";
```

remove ~ operator from the path

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Popup message ');window.location='webform.aspx';</script>");`

Change location and message.

Happy coding 
Regards,
AK.